# Burger King toy of Bald Guy with blue markings on his forehead

Tags: character-identification

My niece was given this toy at Burger King, but we don't know him. A Google Image search just gave "figurine" as a result.

[image: Bald Guy™]

Can you help us give Bald Guy™ a name?

Comment: His colouration would indicate a bad-guy.

Comment: Saw the title on the Hot Questions list and thought of Aang.  Wrong bald guy with blue markings.

Comment: I clicked the link, half expecting to see the Airbender.

Comment: _I thought for sure it was going to be the The Boy in the Iceberg_

Comment: Heh, https://www.reddit.com/r/Weird/comments/ter6sn/someone_screwed_this_to_a_tree_way_out_in_the/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is [Kaos](http://skylanders.wikia.com/wiki/Kaos) from *Skylanders*.

> Kaos is an evil Portal Master and the primary antagonist of the Skylanders series. He plots to take over Skylands and was responsible for banishing all the Skylanders from their world to Earth after destroying the Core of Light that protected Skylands.

[image: Kaos from Skylanders]

Found by searching for `burger king toy blue markings forehead "blue hands"`, which brought me to this video:

Comment: +1 for indicating _how_ you found it. Finding images via search can be tough if you don't know what you're looking for

Comment: @FreeMan: I try to do that for identification searches if I can. I tried a few different searches before those keywords worked. Using quote marks and using the "site:" limiter are two really useful Google tips. :)

Comment: Thank you! It seems she still prefers _Bald Guy_, but we'll do our best anyway 

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Are you sure she doesn't prefer Bald Guy™?

Comment: And my nephews have confirmed. :-D